How to abi.encodeWithSignature the function which contains structure as the parameter in solidity?
I want to call Uniswap's collect function which is in NonFungiblePositionManager contract using delegatecall. But the collect function takes the structure as the parameter.
Here is the collect function from NonFungiblePositionManager
struct CollectParams {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address recipient;
        uint128 amount0Max;
        uint128 amount1Max;
    }

function collect(CollectParams calldata params)
        external
        payable
        override
        isAuthorizedForToken(params.tokenId)
        returns (uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1)
     {
         // some code
     }


Now how do I abi.encodeWithSignature the above function in solidity?

Since, the collect() function is payable, so you can pass the value using the .call() function.
Here's the minimal implementation to call the collect() function of NonFungiblePositionManager contract by using abi.encodeWithSignature():
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Example {
    struct CollectParams {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address recipient;
        uint128 amount0Max;
        uint128 amount1Max;
    }

    function callCollect(
        address nonFungiblePositionManager,
        CollectParams memory params
    ) external payable returns (uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) {

        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "collect((uint256,address,uint128,uint128))",
            params.tokenId,
            params.recipient,
            params.amount0Max,
            params.amount1Max
        );

        (bool success, bytes memory returnedData) = nonFungiblePositionManager
            .call{value: msg.value}(data);

        require(success, "Call to collect failed");

        // Decode returned data
        (amount0, amount1) = abi.decode(returnedData, (uint256, uint256));
    }
}

Now, after deploying this contract, you can call the callCollect() function by attaching the required ether as value and passing the two arguments as:

nonFungiblePositionManager of type address: the address of the NonFungiblePositionManager whose collect() method you want to call.

params  of type tuple: the parameters of CollectParams struct that you can pass as [tokenId,recipient,amount0Max,amount1Max].


